# Kivy USB Keyboard Double Typing Letters

Tags: python, keyboard, kivy, raspberry-pi3, textinput

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that is running an application using Kivy. There is a USB keyboard connected to allow text input within the application. Every time I type in a text box the letters are double typed. If I press and hold a key, the letter will double type as well. Outside of the application, the keyboard works normally (does not double type letters). It also works normally if I run the application on my PC. How do I prevent my keyboard from double typing within the application?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4253) describes it, I think. But I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config.ini file for kivy had an error. This file was located in the .kivy folder.

Previously under the input section we had the following lines:

```
[input]
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s=probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s=probesysfs,provider=hidinput
%(name)s=probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Removing the last line shown above solved the double typing error.